# Как вывести общее количество товаров? PHP

Tags: php, cart

У меня возникла проблема. Я написал корзину товаров, все вроде прекрасно работает, но я не могу сделать одну вещь: "Вывод общего количества товаров". Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать.

```
    if ($action == "show") {
    if (!(isset($_SESSION['cart']))) {
        echo "У вас нет товаров";
        die();
    }
    $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
    if (count($cart) == 0) {
        echo "У вас нет товаров";
        die();
    }
    $cnt = array();
    foreach ($cart as $id => $value) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tovar` WHERE `id` = '$id'";
        $sql_result = mysqli_query($dbhandle, $sql);
        $cnt[$id] = $value;
        while ($row = $sql_result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "
                <p>Идентификатор товара: ".$row['id']."</p>
                <p>Наименование товара: ".$row['name']."</p>
                <p>Количество товара: ".$value."</p>
                <p>Стоимость товара: ".$row['cost']."</p>
                <p>Описание товара: ".$row['desc']."</p>
                <input type='button' value='Удалить товар из корзины' onclick='delFromCart(".$row['id'].")'>
                <input type='button' value='+' onclick='plustovar(".$row['id'].")'>
                <input type='button' value='-' onclick='minustovar(".$row['id'].")'>
                ";
        }
    }
}

if ($action == 'add') {
    $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    if (isset($cart[$id])) {
        $cart[$id]++;
    } else {
        $cart[$id] = 1;
    }
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
}

if ($action == 'del') {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
    if (isset($cart[$id])) {
        unset($cart[$id]);
    }
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
}

if ($action == 'plus') {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
    if (isset($cart[$id])) {
        $cart[$id]++;
    }
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
}

if ($action == 'minus') {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
    if (isset($cart[$id])) {
        $cart[$id]--;
    } 
    if ($cart[$id] === 0) {
        unset($cart[$id]);
    }
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $cart;
}
```

Comment: А в чем проблема-то? Вот допустим у тебя в комоде три ящика, в одном два носка, во втором - пять и в третьем - один. Ты можешь посчитать, сколько у тебя всего носков? А чем это отличается от текущей задачи?

Comment: А как это сделать? Скажи пожалуйста.
Все уже перепробовал.

Comment: Потому, что у меня получается, только ящики считаются, я не могу считать носки. Я просто совсем новичок...

Comment: расскажи своими словами, как будешь считать носки?

Comment: Открывать ящик, пересчитывать, закрывать, открывать другой. 
Но как это сделать в коде?

Comment: а где здесь **подсчет общего количества?** ты только ящики открывал-закрывал. СЧИТАТЬ ты как будешь?

Comment: array_sum(); Верно же?

Comment: вот что ты наугад тыкаешься? надо нормально словами сказать. это важно. **невозможно написать код**, если ты не представляешь себе алгоритм. Ты сначала в голове должен полностью представлять решение проблемы, по шагам. Если ты его представляешь, то можешь рассказать. Вот и надо рассказать своими словами ход действий, который даст тебе сумму. да array_sum поможет. но это бессмысленно в твоем случае. Это ты сначала зачем-то собираешь все носки в пакет, а потом только их в пакете пересчитваешь. А СРАЗУ без пакета нельзя носки посчитать? А без массива $cnt посчитать  товары - совсем никак?

Comment: Я не придуриваюсь и не издеваюсь с носками. Наоборот - я пытаюсь донести до тебя самую важную вещь в программировании. Если ты не можешь четко и пошагово описать свои действия даже в такой простой задаче, то ты не сможешь программировать. потому что программирование - это составление алгоритма. А только потом написание кода, который этот алгоритм реализует.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$generalAmount = 0;
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $count){
     $generalAmount += $count;
}
echo "Общее кол-во товаров: ".$generalAmount;
```

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы тебе сразу же не записать количество в сессию? Например `$cart['totalAmount'] += 'количество'`

Comment: Потому что это не имеет смысла. Не нужно дублировать данные.

Answer (score -1):

Присвоить товарам категорию, и через select отправить запрос по типу.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM product WHERE category = 'носки'
```

Вариант 2

```
$result = SELECT * FROM product WHERE category = 'носки'
count($result);
```

Comment: Нельзя настолько невнимательно читать вопрос

Comment: Это конечно правильно вроде, но для абсолютно другого действия, а именно подсчет общего количества товаров с такой категорией в базе данных. А мне получается нужно подсчитывать общие товары, которые хранятся в массиве сессии.